# Is there any way to improve Dart (dart2js) compile times?

Tags: performance, compilation, dart, dart2js

I'm trying to move from TypeScript to Dart. TypeScript compiles almost immediately - Dart takes more than 5 seconds to compile a Hello World program! Am I missing something? Are there any possible ways to improve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually not much of an issue when developing with Dart because Dartium, a Chromium derivative executes Dart directly.

Only for testing compatibility with other browsers and for deployment it is necessary to build to JavaScript.

`pub serve` a Dart development web server does dart-to-js compilation on-the-fly with a lot of caching which usually improves transpilation times for reloads (after some warmup time) if you need JS during development with non-Dartium browsers.

Comment: Did you mean "seconds"? It's not 5 minutes, thank God.

Comment: Sorry, misread that in your question. 5 seconds is a good time for dart2js.

Comment: I've checked out Dartium and that seems to be a real solution! Dartium will still use Dart VM when used with `pub serve`, won't it?

Comment: Yup, `pub serve` serves Dart or transpiled JS source code depending on what the browser requests. The `dart.js` script tag requests JS source in browsers without native Dart support.

Comment: Dartium is a few versions behind Chromium currently because there is a bigger rework going on. An up-to-date version will be shipped soon.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.
So it (ts compiler) translates from a higher level programming language to a lower level programming language.

Dart is an open-source, scalable programming language, with robust libraries and runtimes.
So it (dart2js compiler) is a source-to-source compiler (transpiler) that takes the source code of a program written in one programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in another programming language.

I think that explains everything.

Comment: Well, Go compiles a Hello World in 0.5 s... But I get your point.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Go compiler (as and Typescript) translates to the low level programming language. Dart compiler translates to another high level programming language. If you try to translate the Go source to another language (eg. to Java or to C#) then this process will take much more time (the same as and with Dart when it translates to Javascript).